# How to parse JSON files with double-quotes inside strings in Python?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to read a JSON file in Python. Some of the lines have strings with double quotes inside:

```
{"Height__c": "8' 0\"", "Width__c": "2' 8\""}
```

Using a raw string literal produces the right output:

```
json.loads(r"""{"Height__c": "8' 0\"", "Width__c": "2' 8\""}""")
{u'Width__c': u'2\' 8"', u'Height__c': u'8\' 0"'}
```

But my string comes from a file, ie:

```
s = f.readline()
```

Where:

```
>>> print repr(s)
'{"Height__c": "8\' 0"", "Width__c": "2\' 8""}'
```

And json throws the following exception:

```
json.loads(s) # s = """{"Height__c": "8' 0\"", "Width__c": "2' 8\""}"""
ValueError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 21 (char 20)
```

Also,

```
>>> s = """{"Height__c": "8' 0\"", "Width__c": "2' 8\""}"""
>>> json.loads(s)
```

Fails, but assigning the raw literal works:

```
>>> s = r"""{"Height__c": "8' 0\"", "Width__c": "2' 8\""}"""
>>> json.loads(s)
{u'Width__c': u'2\' 8"', u'Height__c': u'8\' 0"'}
```

Do I need to write a custom Decoder?

Comment: Then your *file data* is corrupted. Can you show us what `print repr(s)` prints?

Comment: Can you put the file somewhere where we can download it?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: no need, not if we get a proper `repr()` string representation.

Comment: Here is repr(s): ` '\'{"Height__c": "8\\\' 0"", "Width__c": "2\\\' 8""}\'' ` @Martijn Pieters

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add that (use 4 spaces indentation to mark it as a code block).

Comment: So the data is wrong, at the end there is no backslash before the double quote after the 8. No backslash after the 0 either.

Comment: @user2911598: that data does **not** contain backslashes escaping your nested double quotes. If those double quotes are always located right after a digit (and perhaps right before another quote) we can perhaps repair it. Are there any other such unescaped quotes in there that don't fit that pattern?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: thanks for your help. I see the problem with the lack of backlashes escaping the nested double quotes in repr(s). Could it be that f.readline() is transforming the data when reading it? Because the file does contain valid JSON (by jlint)

Comment: The correct repr: `print(repr(s))` -> `'{"Height__c": "8\' 0\\"", "Width__c": "2\' 8\\""}'`

Comment: @user2911598: no, `f.readline()` does no such translation.

Comment: @user2911598: that data would *not* pass a proper JSON linter.

Comment: @user2911598: backslash has special meaning in both json and Python string literals i.e., don't copy from a json file into Python source code without changes and vice versa e.g., if you see `"\""` in a json file then the correct Python string literal is: `'"\\""'` (note: the backslash is escaped).

Comment: note: the escaping exists only in string literals there are no escaping in Python strings in memory i.e., if you see `["\""]` in a file then `json.load(file)` must work in this case without any escaping (it should return a list with a string inside `[u'"']`). Note: `repr(file.read())` would return the correct Python string literal: `'["\\""]'` (escaping is done by `repr()`).

Comment: Problem solved. I had two problems, first I had bug that led me to believe a proper line of json was not loading correctly, which in fact it was. Then, I copied/pasted the json directly from the source file just like @J.F.Sebastian explained. The source data was correct and json was doing the right thing. Thank you for helping me understand and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The data file you have does *not* escape the nested quotes correctly; this can be hard to repair.

If the nested quotes follow a pattern; e.g. always follow a digit and are the last character in each string you can use a regular expression to fix these up. Given your sample data, if all you have is measurements in feet and inches, that's certainly doable:

```
import re
from functools import partial

repair_nested = partial(re.compile(r'(\d)""').sub, r'\1\\""')

json.loads(repair_nested(s))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import json
>>> import re
>>> from functools import partial
>>> s = '{"Height__c": "8\' 0"", "Width__c": "2\' 8""}'
>>> repair_nested = partial(re.compile(r'(\d)""').sub, r'\1\\""')
>>> json.loads(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 381, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 21 (char 20)
>>> json.loads(repair_nested(s))
{u'Width__c': u'2\' 8"', u'Height__c': u'8\' 0"'}
```